# Indexing an alphabetically sorted list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, indexing

I have an array with a list of objects sorted alphabetically ignoring the letters case (used a `lowerCaseString` method) and I need to sort it into an array of arrays one for each letter +1 for non alpha characters.

A simple way of doing it would be to loop through the source array with a giant 27 stack deep `if else if else if else...`. Needless to say I don't think that's a very good solution so I was thinking if I could convert the first letter of the string that I'm sorting by to an int I could then use that to calculate an index to sort the object into.

So I need help with either implementing this or finding a better way to do it.

I'm working on the iPhone platform so I have access to the cocoa and core apple librarys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a "sorted" NSMutableArray and it would hold your 27 "letter" NSMutableArray objects that each hold your objects.

You can also use an NSArray of the 26 letters (as NSString objects) and use `indexOfObject:` to get the index from the "sorted" array of the "letter" array that object should be added to (if it returns NSNotFound, use 26 as the index since that's your non-alpha array).

For example, if you are sorting NSString objects, you could do it like this:

```
NSArray *originalArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A object",@"B object",@"C object",@"123 object",nil];

// init with all 26 lowercase letters here
NSArray *letters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil];

// create sorted and letter arrays
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[letters count]+1];
for (int i = 0; i < [letters count] + 1; i++) {
    // use an appropriate capacity here
    NSMutableArray *letterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    [sortedArray addObject:letterArray];
    [letterArray release];
}

// sort originalArray into sortedArray
for (NSString *string in originalArray) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [[string substringWithRange:[string rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0]] lowercaseString];

    int index = [letters indexOfObject:firstLetter];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        // use non-alpha array
        index = [letters count];
    }

    NSMutableArray *letterArray = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:index];
    [letterArray addObject:string];
}

NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

In regular c, `str[0] - 'a'` would give you an integer from 0 to 25 for strings starting with lowercase-alpha characters. Then you just have one `if` to check for non-alpha initial characters.